# Analysis of complex survey design with multiple plausible values

Tags: r, survey

I am working with several large databases (e.g. PISA and NAEP) that use a complex survey design with replicate weights and multiple plausible values. I can address the former using the survey package. However, does there exist an R package/function to analyze the latter?

For reference, I have found this article to provide a good overview of the issue: http://www.ierinstitute.org/fileadmin/Documents/IERI_Monograph/IERI_Monograph_Volume_02_Chapter_01.pdf

Comment: to correctly work with pisa's complex sample + multiply-imputed variables in the r language, [start here](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/program%20for%20international%20student%20assessment%20%28pisa%29).  that code does all of the setup for you.  ;)

Comment: in addition to pisa, https://github.com/ajdamico/usgsd now has timss, pirls, and piaac - all of which are plausible value-based surveys.  the output of my r syntax matches official publications exactly.  good luck!

Comment: You could try this package, it supports multiple studies with complex sampling and assessment design: https://cran.r-project.org/package=RALSA It also has a GUI which makes life a lot easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how the general idea of 'plausible values' differs from using multiple imputation to generate several sets of imputed values (such as the the Amelia package does).  But Thomas Lumley's mitools package can be used to combine the various sets of imputed values, and it might be the case that it can be used to combine your sets of plausible values to obtain the 'correct' standard errors of the estimates.

Comment: David, you are correct that they do not differ from multiple imputations. I was unaware of the mitools package. I have been looking at Amelia and mice but could not figure out how to use their combining functions with a plain data frame (i.e. something not generated from the imputation functions). Thanks.

Comment: @jbryer - here's some code that I used in a program for NHANES data:

f=amelia(dataframe, m = 5, noms=cs(sexc,racec,strata,psu), idvars='seqn',ps2=2)

The imputed values are based on all other variables in your dataframe, so you might want to subset only the variables of interest.  The output, f, is a list of lists, with the first set of imputed values being in f$imp$imp1 - str(f) would be a good idea.

The vignette for this package is very helpful, and it explains how to construct a 'priors matrix' (but the authors don't seem very fond of a this matrix)

Comment: hi @DavidF i believe `amelia` will give the wrong standard errors / variances for complex survey data.  you could test things out and try to match an official cdc nhanes publication, but it's easier to just use `survey` plus `mitools` which were designed specifically for data of this structure

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Caro develop an R package for large scale assessments. You can find it here http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/intsvy/index.html

This is code example using the regression command, over the plausible values on Mathemathics:

```
## Not run:
# Table I.2.3a, p. 305, International Report 2012
pisa.reg.pv(pvlabel="MATH", x="ST04Q01", by = "IDCNTRYL", data=pisa)
```

Although, I'm not sure if this package can be used to analyze NAEP data.
I hope this fulfill your purposes; at least partially.

Comment: hi, seems like a lot of work to learn an entirely new framework for just four surveys?  PISA, PIAAC, TIMSS, and PIRLS are all easily analyzed using `survey` and `mitools` packages together.  you can find detailed usage examples here https://github.com/ajdamico/usgsd using the (much more general) syntax that `survey` package users are already familiar with.

Comment: I will do check your examples. Thanks Anthony!

Comment: @Anthony Damico: There is a recent R package which supports much more studies: https://cran.r-project.org/package=RALSA It also has a GUI for those who lack experience with R.

Answer (score 0):

As of survey version 3.36 there's `withPV`

```
data(pisamaths, package="mitools")
des<-svydesign(id=~SCHOOLID+STIDSTD, strata=~STRATUM, nest=TRUE,
    weights=~W_FSCHWT+condwt, data=pisamaths)

options(survey.lonely.psu="remove")

results<-withPV(list(maths~PV1MATH+PV2MATH+PV3MATH+PV4MATH+PV5MATH),
   data=des,
   action=quote(svyglm(maths~ST04Q01*(PCGIRLS+SMRATIO)+MATHEFF+OPENPS, design=des)))

summary(MIcombine(results))
```